# Copying SharePoint list data

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a requirement where we use calendar to enter events for a year and we are looking to automate copying the events from one year to another year. Limitation is I don't have access to server so I couldn't deploy the server side custom code that I had developed. Is there way I can create a custom solution without touching server to deploy?

Comment: You could use CSOM to do this.

Comment: What version of sharepoint?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if CSOM in 2010 supported new calendar items. But you should definitely check it out.

If CSOM doesn't support it, your next best alternative is to use the lists.asmx service to read existing items and create new ones based on them. [Check this out.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx)